# How can I coat a Jacuzzi tub to cover stains?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, stain

I have a badly stained bathtub that's in good shape. The previous owner put in a Jacuzzi tub in 2018 and I'm guessing immediately began dying her hair blue and purple leaving this great tub/shower with awesome stains of both all over the floor and walls of the tub. We don't really have it in the budget to replace the tub but is there a paint that we can repaint the tub with? It is a white fiberglass tub.

Comment: There are companies that will refurbish or resurface a tub. I'm sure that there are DIY versions, as well. Including a picture may help someone with a suggestion, it may not. At a minimum, it will amuse and entertain your audience. ;)

Comment: Paint rarely works well - peeling paint will quickly look worse than purple-blue stains, IMHO. What, if anything, have your tried to remove the stains? You'll need to stick to products that won't damage the plastic, but that might be a better route to follow, IMHO.

Comment: A five second Google search returned many options. What's the question? Keep in mind that specific product suggestions and reviews are off topic here.

Comment: Would try a boat repair/sale shop.  They do fibreglass work and probably have better stuff, than what is sold to DIYers.

Comment: try hydrogen peroxide

Comment: yeah, bleach is definately worth trying.

Comment: there's lots of common solvents, one should work: acetone, wd40, 91% isopropyl, drain-o, crisco, lighter fluid (naptha), gasoline (be careful), and vinegar are all cheap options worth trying.